# DB Design: What are benefit(s) of creating a table to hold all IDs of system entities?

Tags: database, database-design

In a simple Data Base design, entity tables have IDs (mostly auto increment)

But there are some system e.g. vtiger CRM that use a master table to store all newly created IDS. 

My question is:

1. What is the benefits of described approach.
2. What is the name of described approach, if any. I mean what do designers call this
   method?

moodle is another example of this method too. An example in Moodle:

`mdl_context` has all IDs of other modules:

- mdl_context - id - contextlevel - instanceid - path - depth
- values - 115 - 50 - 17 - /1/84/90/115 - 4

`instanceid` is the ID of other entity and `contextlevel` shows the table, for example 50 is a code for course table.

Without having `mdl_context`, `mdl_course` had it's own ID, so why does `mdl_course exists?

Answer (score 1):

You may simply think about this when your database doesn't support auto increment columns and you would have to implement auto incremental values yourself.
Or due to limitations of specific implementation of auto increment in a database, based on you business rules, you need to customize auto increment module.

for example 
 
When `gaps in the column values, are important to NOT Happens`.

Consider the selling scenario in witch you need to have exact sequence of numbers for billing_ number column. Using an auto increment approach will cause some problems: 
1- If any bill, would be rejected you would lose a number (`Rollback scenario`) 
2- In case of DELETE operation on Billing table (if happens) you will lose a number(`Delete scenario`) 
3- In some distributed(clustered) DB environments like Oracle RAC (having multiple RDBMS nodes) and using oracle sequences as auto increment strategy, we must use a `CACHE interval` to maintain integrity, so again some numbers will be lost.

In these cases you may use a metadata table like `crm_entity` holding last used value per table on it(or any other information if needed). locking the metadata table will be inevitable, so in heavy TPS, there will be performance issue.

Comment: So you mean using a master table prevents losing an id?

Comment: Yes, when having gaps is not appreciated and you need to not replay on a specific DB features like SQL Server auto increment.

Comment: suppose we have 10 contacts (1 to 10), still we can delete contact 3 (then crm_entity flags it as deleted), anyway we have lost id 3 on contact table

Comment: When using auto increment. yes 3 is lost. when using metadata table GetNextId for Contract table could be implemented in the way that returns 3. using metadata table will give use new possibilities in a cost.

Comment: @HPM: there is no such thing as "losing an ID". If the ID is the primary key, the actual value **does not matter**. The only place where gaplesse, consecutive identifiers might make sense is required by law, e.g. invoice numbers and such things. A "normal" primary key has absolutely no meaning, to the presence of "gaps" doesn't mean anything either.

Comment: @horse, "If the ID is the primary key, the actual value does not matter ... has absolutely no meaning". Those are totally unhelpful over-generalisations. Very obviously the values of most keys *do* matter a great deal and have a very important role and meaning to their end users as identifying information in the database. Asserting that because some attribute(s) just happen to be designated as a "primary" key they should/will not have meaning is at best just a preference and recommendation and at worst no better than blind dogma.

Comment: I updated my question: *Both crm_entity and contacts table has it's own auto Increment ID.* I mean contacts has it's own auto increment Id, why a master table exists?

Comment: Can you mention that what data contains on crm_entity for Contract table, I mean  some other info will be stored in crm_entity = ?

Comment: I think you should do some DML (insert, update, delete) on Contract table and track the changes in crm_entity to discover how the designer have used the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

SQL DBMSs typically provide a key generator feature that can be directly associated with a column in a table, variously known as Identity or auto-incrementing columns. These suffer certain disadvantages however. The syntax is often highly proprietary and awkward to work with and the key generator usually comes with inbuilt limitations, such as not permitting updates or inserts or only allowing one such column per table. Table-based generator functions normally only work on insert, which means the value can't be accessed and used until after the row has been inserted, and they are associated with one table only, making it impossible to generate key values that are shared and distributed between tables.

To overcome those and other limitations, table-independent key generators are often used instead. Some DBMSs (Oracle, SQL Server) support this directly with special Sequence-generator objects that are independent of tables but other DBMSs do not. So keeping a sequence-generating table separate from other tables is a useful general way to create sequences without relying on DBMS-specific features.

Comment: I updated my question: Both crm_entity and contacts table has it's own auto Increment ID. I mean contacts has it's own auto increment Id, why a master table exists? I do not think existance of master table is because of generating IDs.